# Fluid in Containers with the same Volume but Different Dimensions

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Considering two (significantly large) containers with equal volumes, one thin and tall, the other wide and short, both filled with water. If pipes with identical cross-sectional areas are used to empty them simultaneously, which container will empty faster? Or will they empty at the same time? Is pressure a factor?

Comment: Please provide schematic diagrams, showing where the drain is located.

Comment: Did you try applying Bernoulli's principle and the continuity equation?